# Agrupar registros en una sola fila

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, sql-server-2019

tengo la siguiente consulta en SQL SERVER 2019, la cual me trae tickets asignados a un usuario con mas de 2 dias:

```
SELECT 
t.TicketId,
DATEDIFF(day, t.TicketFechaInicio, GETDATE()) as dias, 
t.TicketFolio,
t.TicketProgramaId,
u.UsuarioEmail,
u.UsuarioId
FROM 
Tickets t
INNER JOIN
UsuariosProgramas up
ON up.ProgramaId = t.TicketProgramaId
INNER JOIN
usuarios u
ON u.UsuarioId = up.UsuarioId  
WHERE 
t.TicketFechaFin IS NULL 
AND t.TicketProgramaId IS NOT NULL 
AND DATEDIFF(day, t.TicketFechaInicio, GETDATE()) > 2
AND u.PerfilId <> 5 AND u.PerfilId <> 3;
```

La cual me da los siguientes registros:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como crear una consulta para obtener un resultado agrupando por el numero de tickets, y los folios en un solo string:

| Conteo | UsuarioEmail | Folios |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 8 | usuario1@prueba.com.mx | 2022062815147521,2022062815177621,2022062815187731... |
| 19 | usuario2@prueba.com.mx | 2022062814287411,202207131553217211,202207131555217411... |
| 6 | usuario3@prueba.com.mx | 202207051310197221,2022062815187731,20220705163228711... |

Agradezco su ayuda

Comment: Qué motor de base de datos estás usando?

Comment: SQL SERVER 2019

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En estos casos `STRING_AGG` te puede servir:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(1) Conteo,
       X.UsuarioEmail,
       STRING_AGG(X.TicketFolio,',') TicketFolio
FROM (
  SELECT 
  t.TicketId,
  DATEDIFF(day, t.TicketFechaInicio, GETDATE()) as dias, 
  t.TicketFolio,
  t.TicketProgramaId,
  u.UsuarioEmail,
  u.UsuarioId
  FROM 
  Tickets t
  INNER JOIN
  UsuariosProgramas up
  ON up.ProgramaId = t.TicketProgramaId
  INNER JOIN
  usuarios u
  ON u.UsuarioId = up.UsuarioId  
  WHERE 
  t.TicketFechaFin IS NULL 
  AND t.TicketProgramaId IS NOT NULL 
  AND DATEDIFF(day, t.TicketFechaInicio, GETDATE()) > 2
  AND u.PerfilId <> 5 AND u.PerfilId <> 3
) X
GROUP BY X.UsuarioEmail
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, es lo que necesitaba

Answer (score 1):

Como no has puesto datos, y solo imagenes, voy a construir la consulta con una variable Tipo Table para ofrecerte una de las posibles soluciones.

```
Declare @table table (TicketId int, Folio varchar(100), UsuarioEmail 
varchar(100))
Insert into @table (TicketId, Folio, UsuarioEmail)
values
(5, '123','usuario1@prueba.com'),
(6, '124','usuario1@prueba.com'),
(7, '125','usuario1@prueba.com'),
(8, '201','usuario2@prueba.com'),
(9, '202','usuario2@prueba.com'),
(10,'203','usuario2@prueba.com');


With Source as (
    Select t.TicketId, t.Folio, t.UsuarioEmail from @table t
), r as (
    Select COUNT(1) as veces, UsuarioEmail
    From Source 
    Group by UsuarioEmail
)
Select *, 
            STUFF(
            (
                SELECT ';' + CAST(bx.Folio AS VARCHAR(20))
                FROM Source bx
                where bx.UsuarioEmail = r.UsuarioEmail 
                FOR XML PATH('')
            ),1,1,'') as Folios 
    from r ;
```

Está dentro de una cte llamada source, para que cambies, esa parte por tu query.

[image: Result]

La concatenación la realizamos con [For Xml Path](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/xml/for-xml-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16)

Con [Stuff](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/stuff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) le quitamos el primer ; generado.

Y la subconsulta que retorna esos datos sobre el conjunto `source` la relacionamos con el conjunto por `usuarioEmail`

Nota: He visto tu query y se me hace muy extraño `AND u.PerfilId <> 5 AND u.PerfilId <> 3;` . Quizá es más visual `And u.perfilId not in (3,5)`. La query no va a cambiar nada, porque el optimizador de consultas, la va a realizar de la misma manera, pero el código queda un poco más "bonito" en mi opinión.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la nota, te doy un voto arriba tambien